# Are WordPress Jetpack stats accurate?

Tags: wordpress.com

I have a blog on WordPress running for a few months now, and is a free subscription. It has only the default Jetpack Analytics which shows Page views, visitors and the same by country.

This is a tech blog and doesn't show up on Google Search (even when I type a blog title). There are only around 10 people at my workplace (India) who browse this site and not everyday.

However, the stats show numbers like these:

[image]

I'm quite surprised by these numbers:

1. The high number for India
2. The 10s-100s of visits from other countries

By the nature of its content, that is not so believable for me.
So, are these stats really correct?

Comment: I don't think they count something that isn't there. Also the stats are as accurate as possible. They are professional. Well is but this really sounds strange. Maybe someone tried to bring down the site by flooding some kind of requests. Are the access times spread over time? However it really seems people or something was actually accessing your site. WP uses ping services or maybe the WordPress.com site index? Dunno.

Comment: @UwePfeifer. The no.s in India let's suppose might be close(let's just suppose)...but from another countries..!!?!Definitely strange. If WP really does ping and add them as views & visits...isn't it wrong..

Comment: A quick check: Use Google to see if anyone is linking to your page. Try, e.g. *link:http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.html*

Answer (score 1):

Well my private blog only shows 1-2 hits per day so for me it's not counting something that isn't there. Botnets can be used to flood websites and they might be spread over different countries.

Answer (score 1):

Could be [spam bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spambot).

Read [How to Stop Spam Bots from Ruining Your Analytics Referral Data](https://moz.com/blog/how-to-stop-spam-bots-from-ruining-your-analytics-referral-data) for possible reasons. One thing they mention there is spam bots who do not properly indicate that they are only crawling<sup>*</sup>.
They suggest using [Wp-Ban](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ban/) to block these:

> I’ve used the plugin Wp-Ban before, and it makes it easy to block unwanted visitors. Wp-ban gives you the ability to ban users by IP, IP range, host name, user agent and referrer URL from visiting your WordPress blog all from within the WordPress admin panel. This a great option for people who don’t want to edit their .htaccess file or don’t feel comfortable doing so

More information: [What To Do About a Fake BS Surge of Google Analytics Visits](http://www.davebuesing.com/google-analytics-spam-traffic-bots/),
or Google for things like [spam bots website traffic](https://www.google.com/search?q=spam+bots+website+traffic) or [fake web traffic](https://www.google.com/search?q=fake+web+traffic).

There also used to be a side effect of [click farms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_farm) (you can look at this as the 'manual' form of spam bots) where the people working there *not only* click on the sites they are getting paid for, but also on random other sites in order to try to circumvent detection/filters. I don't think this happens in your case, nowadays click farms are used more often [for social media likes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVfHeWTKjag) than 'old fashioned' website visits. That video explains this 'clicking on other random pages' around 7:40

<sup>* I'm assuming that Jetpack would exclude these from the count, that's the usual/sensible thing to do</sup>